# How to set background for textview in code?

Tags: android, textview

I set textview background equal transparent, and now I want change it's background in code.
when click on mybtn (this is a button) change textview background, how do it?

code:

```
Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_dialog);
btn.setBackgroundColor(color.transparent);
btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt);
    txt.setBackgroundColor(??????);

    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "this test is ok!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }
});
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can set any color using this:

```
txt.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#BABABA")); // set any custom color as background color
```

or

```
txt.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED); // set default RED color as background color
```

Answer (score 20):

**Dont use `setBackgroundDrawable` but use::**

```
@Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt);
    txt.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.textview_logo);

    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "this test is ok!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }
});
```

Make sure `textview_logo` are stay in drawable folder

for set background :

```
txt.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
```

Comment: excuse me, I edit my code
Due to I wana setBackgroungColor for my textview
please help me

Answer (score 1):

There 3 duntiond for setting background.

```
txt.setBackgroundResource(int rsid);
txt.setBakgroundDrawable(Drawable object);
txt.setBackgroundColor(color id);
```

The most suitable is 
**txt.setBackgroundResource(int rsid)**; where you can directly set your image from drawable folder as below:

```
txt.setBakgroundResource(R.drawable.image_name);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need indentify by color you should use:

```
txt.setBackgroundColor(R.color.someColorInColorsXML);
```

or

```
txt.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(AARRGGBB));
```

Answer (score 0):

Post API level 23, I believe best practice is to use:

```
setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.my_color));
```

This should also ensure backward compatibility is sustained (not tested myself)